# MySql migrate to Aurora without taking downtime

Tags: mysql, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I've AWS MySQL RDS instance located at Singapore, and I'm planning to migrate it to AWS Aurora (Mumbai). This process roughly takes about 30-40 minutes. I don't want to take any downtime while migration process. My App server created on node.js and also hosted on EC2 at Singapore. How Do I do HA (High Availability) of my database? What should I need to do? Should I make any changes in my server logic on node.js? or make any replication between 2 databases (MySql & Aurora)? or I need to create load balancer to achieve his?

In sort While migration process, I don't want any downtime and my database serves as usual to my users/client.

Comment: Voted to close (migrate) to Server Fault site

Comment: Thanks @Drew for suggestion. How Do I migrate to Server Fault site? Or I have to write there same question there. I am new here. :)

Comment: I can have others close vote it for you and it will just pop over there. Or you can post it there and delete here. Which do you prefer? [Link](http://serverfault.com/)

Comment: @Drew. Ok I will going to post there as new question and delete from here. But If I am not deleting from here, what will happen? There should be more chance to get answer? and what about "Database Administrator" side? Should I post there also?

Comment: Give me a little while. I will try to ping a gent or two first over here

Comment: What volume of requests are you achieving, what is the size of this, and when are you planning this by the way?

Comment: @Drew, about 16gb in size and 300-400 queries/sec. and would like to migrate as early as possible. :) may within 5-6 days

Answer (score 1):

I have done both migrations Singapore to Mumbai and MySQL to Aurora. I will recommend to take one step at a time.. Looks like your website is important as you are so particular about zero downtime.. So, take measured risks.

We never know what fails during these big engineering release. Worst part is that MySQL to Aurora is a "No coming back" release as there is no migration from "Aurora to MySQL".

I will recommend that for Aurora to Mysql go through serious testing; because I did faced few issues like opt file missing, tmp database not supported in Aurora.

For Singapore to Mumbai; make sure your  application uses an internal dns name like abc.internal which is CNAME to actual endpoint. Best way with minimal downtime is to create replica in Mumbai --> make master as readOnly --> promote replica to master --> now change abc.internal to new endpoint.

Aurora to Mysql there will be downtime depending on your db size. Please remember that some downtime is ok; but you cannot afford to loose any data.